# RSS update checker, alternative to FileHippo?

Tags: rss, updates

I have a list of different applications that I want to be kept up-to-date with the latest version.
e.g. Subversion, TortoiseSVN, Paint.NET, Notepad2, etc.

Every now and then I check the website or RSS feed for these applications to see if there is a new version. This is tedious and I want it to be collated into one place (one RSS feed would be fine).

I am not interested in FileHippo or any other similar software because it won't be allowed to go through my work's firewall/proxy. I know I could monitor FileHippo's own RSS feed but this contains way too much software and I am only interested in a small percentage of them. (I wonder if there's any way to filter an RSS feed?)

All suggestions welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already use a feed aggregator, such as [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader)? Google Reader can create a "bundle", which is a single feed that takes content from multiple feeds.

Alternatively, it is possible to filter the pre-aggregated FileHippo feed using something like [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).

Comment: ... Google Reader can track changes on pages without necessarily finding a feed (recently new feature)

Comment: Yahoo Pipes is very cool. I used it to make a filtered feed of all the stuff I am interested in off filehippo's RSS feed, as well as other RSS feeds that filehippo does not track. The single feed is now on my iGoogle. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/) will display pop-up notifications on your desktop when there are updates in your RSS feeds.  It also supports keyword filters, so you could filter out everything you aren't interested in.

You could use the keyword filtering with the FileHippo feed, or you can just subscribe to the individual feeds for the apps you have.

Disclaimer: I created this software. :)